# CreatParams to remove titlebar (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, createparams

I'm trying to build a custom form. I plan on building my own titlebar, so, I need to remove the standard one.

Here is the code so far.

```
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get

        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams

            cp.Style = cp.Style Or Not CInt(WindowStyles.WS_CAPTION)
            Return cp

    End Get
End Property
```

There is a small white frame always drawn. Can't get rid of that. This, with WS_CAPTION was a random test (that worked). So I have no idea where to go from this.
I'm using VB.NET 2015, Win10.

[image]

Comment: You can set the Property FormBorderStyle to none in the designer, or in code. this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

Comment: Actually its `Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None` @Tomato32. ;) OP is using `vb` ***not*** `c#`.

Comment: It is a crappy bug in Windows 10, currently without a known workaround.  I suppose you'll have a settle for a less garish BackColor so it doesn't stick out so bad.

Comment: Your statement to remove `WS_Caption` should use `And` instead of `Or`.

Comment: The idea is to have an "empty canvas" to build a custom/skinned form. I'm trying several approachs, like through WM_NCPAINT, or WM_NCCALCSIZE, but the results are...weird. Usually needing workarounds, and for a non-professional programmer like me, it's a world of pain. Setting the border to none, I loose the blur around the form. That is even worst to get back with workarounds. Thanks anyway to you all.